# UWP - C#: Save Uri into SQLite or how to convert string into Uri when I load a gridview?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have to use an Image for `GridViewItem` style, every `GridViewItem` represents an object saved in a SQLite database, when I save a new object into the db I have to select from a combobox which image it uses.

This is the definition of the Combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="UriImage" Width="200" RelativePanel.Below="ActiveToggle">
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Element1" x:Name="element1" IsSelected="True"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Element2" x:Name="element2"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Element3" x:Name="element3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Then I created this to match the corresponding URI of the image to each ComboBoxItem

```
string ImageUriString=""; 

if (UriImage.SelectedValuePath == "Element1")
      ImageUriString = "ms-appx:///Assets/Orchid_2_FF.png";
else if (UriImage.SelectedValuePath == "Element2")
      ImageUriString = "ms-appx:///Assets/sapphire_orchid_FF.png";
else if (UriImage.SelectedValuePath == "Element3")
      ImageUriString = "ms-appx:///Assets/yellow-cowslip-orchid_FF.png";

Uri UriString = new Uri(ImageUriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Then I added the `Uri` field to the class that represents the object
when I try to save new object I have this Error: `Don't know how to read System.Uri`

To load the objects in the Gridview I use this:

```
private async void ReadAllSystemList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ReadAllSystemsList dbSystems = new ReadAllSystemsList();
   DB_FFSystems = await dbSystems.GetAllFFSystems(); //get all DB Systems       
   listBoxObj.ItemsSource = DB_FFSystems.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).ToList();
}
```

and data Binding from Xaml.

```
<Image Width="350" Height="200" x:Name="ElementImage" Source="{Binding ImageUri}">
```

I thought about saving the URI as a string but how can I convert the string to Uri when loading the Gridview?

Comment: Hi ZampTom, you could use a converter and bind to strings only. But I thought binding to a string for an Imagesource is working anyway?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite cannot store and parse URIs so that is the source of the error you are getting.

You can safely store `string` instead of `Uri` in the database. Usually the ideal approach is to have a simple class that is used as a database model (having a `string` property) and then another class that is used in the presentation layer and that will have `Uri` instead. This way you get a good separation of layers and can have a more practical interface on the presentation layer that is not limited by the database. You can even use libraries like `Automapper` to easily convert from one type to another instead of having to do it property by property.

However, if you don't want to deal with this, there are other options. First of all - you shouldn't have to convert from `string` to `Uri` at all when binding to `Source` of a `Image`. There is an implicit type conversion from `string` to `Uri` built into XAML, so it should work as expected.

Alternatively, you could implement a converter by creating a class deriving from `IValueConverter`. This whould override the `Convert` method and build a `Uri` instance from the passed in `string`. Then you register the converter as a resource with a `x:Key` and use it in code:

```
Source="{Binding ImageUri, Converter={StaticResource StringToUriConverter}"
```